# Select Area of Image

Tags: c#, .net, image, gdi+

I'm trying to select an area of an image I've selected using openfiledialog
The area I'm trying to select is 16x16 from x,y coordinates 5,5
Once selected I want to draw the 16x16 image into another pictureBox at coordinates 0,0

This is the code I've got but I can't get it to select the correct part of the original image, anybody any suggestions as to why it doesn't work?

```
DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
if (result == DialogResult.OK) // Test result.
{
    Image origImage = Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);
    pictureBoxSkin.Image = origImage;
    lblOriginalFilename.Text = openFileDialog1.SafeFileName;

    System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(16, 16);
    Graphics g3 = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
    g3.DrawImageUnscaled(origImage, 0, 0, 16, 16);

    Graphics g2 = pictureBoxNew.CreateGraphics();
    g2.DrawImageUnscaled(bmp, 0, 0, 16, 16);
}
```

Comment: Can you give a little more detail on exactly how it isn't working?

Comment: Use the Graphics.DrawImage(Image, Rectangle, Rectangle, GraphicsUnit) overload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to select the correct section, just replace:

```
g3.DrawImageUnscaled(origImage, 0, 0, 16, 16);
```

with

```
g3.DrawImageUnscaled(origImage, -5, -5, 16, 16);
```

Comment: Negative coordinates, perfect! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

replace this:

```
Graphics g2 = pictureBoxNew.CreateGraphics();
g2.DrawImageUnscaled(bmp, 0, 0, 16, 16);
```

with this:

```
pictureBoxNew.Image = bmp;
```

and you're fine.

Complete code:

```
DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
if (result == DialogResult.OK) // Test result.
{
    Image origImage = Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);
    pictureBoxSkin.Image = origImage;
    lblOriginalFilename.Text = openFileDialog1.SafeFileName;

    System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(16, 16);
    Graphics g3 = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
    g3.DrawImageUnscaled(origImage, 0, 0, 16, 16);

    pictureBoxNew.Image = bmp;
    //Graphics g2 = pictureBoxNew.CreateGraphics();
    //g2.DrawImageUnscaled(bmp, 0, 0, 16, 16);
}
```

When you draw something anywhere *outside a `Paint` event*, it will erased as soon as the control need to be painted again (ie. when restored from minimized state, another window passes over your window, or you call the `Refresh` method). So, put the drawing code for controls inside their `Paint` event, or let the control manage the painting of your image (in this case, assigning an `Image` to the `PictureBox` control).

Comment: I need to keep the Graphics g2 part because in the next loop the coordinates need to change to another position. I'll look into adding to the paint event for the image.