# Smart image square crop in C# to keep maximum visible area and with no distortions

Tags: c#, .net, image, c#-4.0, gdi+

I need a function that crops the image by its shorter dimension (in the center) to make it a square, then resizes it to a particular size. This way, I get the maximum amount of visible content into the output thumbnail and without distortions.

My resize image shrinks the image and causes distortion:

```
public static Image ResizeImage(Image image, Size size, bool preserveAspectRatio = true)
{
        int newWidth;
        int newHeight;

        if (preserveAspectRatio)
        {
            var originalWidth = image.Width;
            var originalHeight = image.Height;
            var percentWidth = size.Width / (float)originalWidth;
            var percentHeight = size.Height / (float)originalHeight;
            var percent = percentHeight < percentWidth ? percentHeight : percentWidth;
            newWidth = (int)(originalWidth * percent);
            newHeight = (int)(originalHeight * percent);
        }
        else
        {
            newWidth = size.Width;
            newHeight = size.Height;
        }

        Image newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);

        using (var graphicsHandle = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
        {
            graphicsHandle.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            graphicsHandle.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            graphicsHandle.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            graphicsHandle.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
        }

        return newImage;
}
```

Note: the crop if needed, should be done from the center of the image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to crop an image using C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/734930/how-to-crop-an-image-using-c)

Comment: @M.Hassan I don't need just cropping. Because if the image is 500x500 and I crop it for 100x100, I get the crop of the original image, which is not resized.

Comment: get height, get width, check which is smaller, cut the other ?

Comment: @Noctis and make it in the center, and how exactly do I cut it the way I want. This is why I asked the question.

Comment: @M.Hassan what do you mean by capture screen? If you mean what images, it can be any image that is not square.

Comment: find smallest, set to 'x'. trim from left (x minus width)/2 and from top (x minus height)/2 with a width of x and a height of x

Comment: execuse me. I deleted my comment,

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14537669/1698987 seems to have what you need

Comment: @Jonathan thanks, that helps a lot

Comment: There is a DrawImage overload with __two rectangles__ which does __exactly__ what you need. Of course you need to calculate those rectangles.